# Laptop won't boot from a USB drive unless I unplug it and plug it back in?

Tags: boot, usb, laptop

I have an old `HP Pavilion g6-1354` and when I try to boot from USB with my bootable `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` on it it won't boot unless I unplug and plug in the USB drive again during the 'wait' screen.
I have tried all the USB ports and using my USB hub. I also did bios reset. Nothing has helped. My BIOS version is F.66 and it is the latest available version on the HP site.

Is there anything I can do to fix it? Are there any unofficial but reliable BIOSes, Bios mods I should try?

Comment: What "wait" screen are you referring to?  What OS is on the internal drive, or are you starting from when you try to boot the USB drive?  If the USB drive is plugged in and you reboot the computer, or start it from power-on, what happens?

Comment: @fixer1234 On the internal drive there is `Windows 7 SP1 x86`. The "wait" screen is probably not a correct word, but I used it because I didn't know the correct one. If the USB drive is plugged in and I reboot then I see that brown-ish _("wait")_ screen with flashing dots like it is loading or searching for something, and I believe it actually does search for the files/the drive, but it can't find anything _(unless, as I said, I do that unplugging/plugging thing)_ and eventually initramfs says `unable to find a medium containing a live file system`.

Comment: It isn't clear from the description what's happening.  At the time of the boot or reboot, there is no other OS involved.  You're starting from scratch.  There's no processing/wait icon.  The system either recognizes the drive or it doesn't at that time.  There's no opportunity to unplug and replug.  Anything you do before the previous session is shut down is irrelevant.

Comment: @fixer1234 [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451662/when-i-start-the-ubuntu-iso-initramfs-says-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing/946334?newreg=a840c1a49d7646ad822a5da65ea3124b), in the comments _Rhys Parsons_ describes exactly the same problem as I have.

Comment: So the unplugging and plugging was Rhys's solution to the boot problem and you're looking for it to just work the way it's supposed to without unplugging and plugging?  Did none of the other solutions on that question work for you?

Comment: @fixer1234 yes, I don't want to just install Ubuntu, but I want to use it as a portable OS. So, while Rhys Parsons' solution is certainly helpful, it's still really only a half-solution. That is, I can live with it, but it's not convenient. I'm not sure what solutions exactly he or she referred to, but if we'll take the ones mentioned in the initial post/question there, like switching from USB 3.0 to 2.0 or from UEFI to Legacy then I couldn't even try them, because I didn't find anything like that in my BIOS. All I tried was reset, and using different USB ports\Hub.